# Local git repo is 45GB, but the remote on bitbucket is only 380MB

Tags: git, version-control, repository, atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken

The title pretty much describes my whole problem. I tried doing `git gc`, but that didn't help at all. I also verified that it is indeed the hidden .git folder that's 45GB in size.

I'm not familiar with the command line at all, I've mostly just used SourceTree/Gitkraken as my git client.

What can I do to solve the problem with my local rep? Is the easiest thing just to delete it and clone it again from remote?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is for a mobile Android/iOS game, with many binary files. This is why the remote is still pretty large.

Comment: Do you use the new Git LFS (Large File Storage)?

Comment: Did you try `git fsck`?

Comment: check what you have in your .gitignore files, there might have files and folders that you are ignoring and they do not go to the remote repository.

Comment: `git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectsize) %(rest)'` tells you the size and committed path to everything you ever committed.

Comment: *I also verified that it is indeed the hidden .git folder that's 45GB in size.* How did you verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just deleting it and cloning the repo again, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do version control for binary files very frequently, this will slow down git and make the space expand quickly.

So better ways to manage binary files in git, you can **delete useless large files from commit histories** or you can **use [git-lfs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-git-lfs-with-bitbucket-828781636.html) to manage your git repo**.